# Guzzle map response to object

Tags: php, guzzle, guzzle6

Is there a way using [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/overview.html) in PHP that when I make a request to an API call that I can map my response to a Response object?

So instead of having to get the response data and then passing my array value as an argument, Guzzle can automatically resolve it to the required class?

In essence, this is what I am doing:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('myapi.users', 'GET');
$responseData = $response->getBody()->getContents();
$user = new User($responseData);
```

However I would like to try and avoid that boilerplate code by doing something like the following:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$user = $client->request('myapi.users', 'GET');
```

**Does Guzzle allow you to map response objects to Responses?**

Thanks!

Comment: I don't thing it is possible with Guzzle, but you can wrap Guzzle and do it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, an HTTP Client (which Guzzle is) is not responsible for that. That's why there is not such a function there.

You can use Guzzle and your own object mapper, BTW, and create an SDK for the API you are using. Like [the GitHub SDK](https://github.com/KnpLabs/php-github-api), for example, that also uses Guzzle inside, but provides a specific interface for the domain.